# Android app for normalizing the volume of mp3 files

Tags: android, audio, mp3

I'm looking for a way to normalize the volume of my mp3s without having to copy them all onto my computer and back again. Anybody know of an existing app for this? Specifically one that lets you set a target volume level across multiple files.

Comment: look into mp3gain

Comment: That one doesn't seem to support setting a target volume level.

Comment: mp3 amplifier is an equivalent to mp3gain, but again, no target volume, only target gain.

Comment: MP3 Amplifier seems to have a setting for bitrate. I would hope it doesn't re-encode the entire file when all it needs to do is apply a ReplayGain?

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk Why do you think mp3gain doesn't support setting a target volume? [Its right there](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kTVd0.png)

Comment: @nixda That's the desktop app...

Answer (score 3):

You can try [MP3Gain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.codebuffet.mp3gain)

Features:

- Works with all android media players
- Supports MP3 and OGG
- Can work in the background - keep doing what you're doing and get a notification when MP3Gain is done!

MP3Gain is free for up to 5 songs each session.

Comment: Any idea, why nearly two years after your answer Google Play claims that this app is not available in my country? Some regions-specific only piece of software?

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry. I had to remove it from the store :( It wasn't working on a few popular devices. I want to make it opensource now so others can help fixing it for non-working devices.

Comment: not sure, if the site is save, but you find some more info here: https://apkdownload.com/down_MP3Gain/co.codebuffet.mp3gain.html but the download seems not to function. Where @user125756 where did you upload your app?