# Volume normalizer for Windows to batch-process large number of MP3 files

Tags: windows, windows-7, audio, mp3, volume-control

I'm looking for a volume normalizer, which can be fed with a directory and then:

- analyse all .mp3 files in that directory,
- calculate normalized volume value, equal for all files,
- batch-rewrite all files, setting volue to that calculated medium value.

[This](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/17542/8327) looked as a good idea for the first moment, but it is for Android and not available in my country.

Do I have any other alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you only need normalizing for mp3-files, you can take a look at [**wxMP3gain**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxmp3gain/):

- uses replay-gain (therefor no [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss))
- add a file or folder for processing
- if you want, you can just analyze the files
- displays and avoids (if configured to do so) clipping
- is capable of doing all in one when configured to do so

[image: wxMP3gain: main window]

---

or maybe you want to try the original (but old) [MP3Gain](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/):

- it is petty old, but should work anyway (and the mp3-format is even older! *--> **use [opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)) instead!***)
- it is very similar to wxMP3gain but seems to be not developed for quite a while now (can be considered as predecessor of wxMP3gain)

Comment: If you would use Opus instead, you would add artifacts when decompressing MP3 files and reencode with Opus

Comment: The installer for wxMP3gain 4.0 contains malware according to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/a5f1879d9e2eacf104e4a8bfbd0361226ed2b991090514a7d8d9d46041c8e13e/detection).

Also, who cares about some hipster audio format? You could've at least recommended ogg if you want to derail the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

[Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) has what you are looking for. You can chain/batch process a directory of files and use the Normalize function on all of them to normalize audio equally against all tracks that you want. Since it appears that you are running on Windows, you might need to get [Lame for Audacity](http://lame.buanzo.org/) to work with and export .mp3 files.

Audacity batch processes uses chains, which can be found through `File -> Edit Chains`. Then, apply the chain (`File -> Apply Chain`) to the audio files you want batch processed and normalized.

Comment: I guess this won't be lossless?

Answer (score 1):

LoudGain seems to be the perfect tool:
https://github.com/Moonbase59/loudgain

> It uses the well-known mp3gain commandline syntax but will never modify the actual audio data.
> Just what you ever wanted: The best of mp3gain, ReplayGain 2.0 and Linux combined.

It reduces gain to -1 dBTP  (instead of 0 dBTP, according to EBU recommendation).  Almost a security margin in the event that the further playout route "only" understands ReplayGain, but has no clipping prevention

Comment: Thanks (+1), sounds like a good idea. However, the fact that it is console only and requires "messing up" with Linux bash to install it on Windows 10 might be a blocker for some. It isn't for me (I am already using Git for Windows and some other *nix-like tools on my W10), but I think that its author(s) could reach a far wider audience, if would consider some automated-like installation solution for Windows. The question is, if they want to reach a wider audience or if this is just "another toy" they do, because they can / want and don't care about possible popularity? Thanks again!